# How to access a parameter supplied by controller with Capybara Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I am trying to test a form that creates a new instance of a model with capybara. The problem is that the user_id is supplied by the controller in the create method and not by the form:

```
@contractor = Contractor.new(contractor_params.merge({user_id:  current_user.id}))
```

Is it now possible to set user_id in my Capybara test, or set the current_user variable in my test in a way that the controller has access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your test, in a before block, stub out `current_user` with a created user, like so (assuming you are using FactoryGirl):

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

before do 
  controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(user)
end
```

When you controller hits `current_user`, it will be the `user` you created.

Comment: Thanks MIke, that's moving me forward but now I get a no method error: `ContractorPages new 
     Failure/Error: controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(user)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ContractorPages::New:0x007fa727a396e0>`

Comment: OK figured it out. Needed ContractorsController instead of controller. Thanks.